# finding third point, provided two points , an angle and the length from one of two given points

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, angle

I have gone through many of the answers and I have not a suitable one so I am asking this question

As provide in the reference image
I have been provide two points A(x, y) and B(x,Y),
an angle Θ and  length d from A(x, Y) to third point C(x,Y).

Basically I need to know how to calculate point C(x, y).

Please any help will be  useful.

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAl84.png)

Answer (score 0):

1) Find the length of 
\begin{equation}
|AB|=\sqrt((x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2
\end{equation}
2) Use the angle between $A$ and $B$ to find the value of the length between $B$ and $d$ line which is orhogonal and let's say that point $D$
\begin{equation}
sin \theta = \frac{|BD|}{|AB|}
\end{equation}
3) Use the Pisagor theorem to find the length between $B$ and $C$ points
\begin{equation}
|BC|^2=|BD|^2+|CD|^2
\end{equation}
4) Using the same idea given 1, find the $x$ and $y$ values for point $C$

Comment: can you provide an reference image for your solution for better understanding, as I couldn't understand what was point D and also how to calculate |CD|

Comment: $D$ point is on the line $d$ and $|BD$ is orthogonal to line$d$

Comment: also how to calculate |CD|

Comment: same equation given 1

Comment: I don't have any co-ordinates of point C or D, then how to calculate |CD| can you provide me an example

Answer (score 0):

You may find the slope of AC using the formula $$ \tan(\theta)=\frac {m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}$$
Where $m_1$ is slope of $AB$ and $m_2$ is slope of $AC$

Then you can locate the point $C$ On the line $AC$ knowing the distance from $A$ to $C$

Comment: can you provide me example

Comment: as i checked you are not considering the distance here

Comment: first you find the equation of AC and then you use the distance to locate C on the line.