# Find third point of triangle knowing two points, an angle and side length

Tags: trigonometry

Given this situation [image]

Where I know points A and B, angle θ and length d, how do I find point C? I already found solutions to this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245262/finding-third-point-provided-two-points-an-angle-and-the-length-from-one-of-t), but I'm a programmer and unsure how to isolate C from the proposed solutions. This is for a graphical measuring tool. I need the Cy = ? and Cx = ? equations. I suspect there will be two solutions to this, points C1 and C2, which is fine since I will pick the one closest to the mouse cursor point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the coordinates of A be $(A_1, A_2)$ etc.

Let's define the vectors:

1. $X = A-B = (A_1-B_1, A_2-B_2) = (X_1, X_2)$
2. $Y = A-C = (A_1-C_1, A_2-C_2) = (Y_1, Y_2)$

Now you can use the definition of dot product.

$\cos(\theta) = \frac{X_1Y_1 + X_2Y_2}{\sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2} \sqrt{Y_1^2 + Y_2^2}}$

Now let's use the other known parameter $d$. The length of vector $Y$ is $d$, so :

$\sqrt{Y_1^2 + Y_2^2} = d$.

This gives you two equations in two variables $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Let's simplify the first equation further:

$X_1Y_1 + X_2Y_2 = d \cos(\theta) \sqrt{X_1^2+ X_2^2}$. Note that all quantities on the right side are known. Let's call the right side $K$.

$X_1Y_1 + X_2Y_2 = K$

$(A_1-B_1)(A_1-C_1) + (A_2-B_2)(A_2-C_2) = K$

This is a linear equation in $C_1$ and $C_2$, so you can write $C_2$ as a function of $C_1$. Then plug it into $\sqrt{Y_1^2 + Y_2^2} = d$. The algebra is messy, but I think it can be solved numerically.

Comment: Ok, so I know the value of cos(θ), the length of vector X and the length of vector Y. So if I understand correctly this gives cos(θ) * |X| * |Y| = (A1-B1)*(A1-C1) + (A2-B2)*(A2-C2). I'm still not sure how I can isolate either C1 or C2 if they are both in the same equation.

Comment: @greenkarmic I added some more hints. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Adi, I kept searching today and found a solution in JavaScript using something called rotation of vectors. I'm not sure if internally it's the same principle as what you suggest, but it does exactly what I wanted to. Still I will accept your answer as I'm sure it's correct as well. Here is the Javascript solution I found, it does not require to know all three sides as the title suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277245/javascript-function-to-find-third-point-of-triangle-when-all-sides-angles-and-f

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution.

Point $C$ is the intersection of the circle centered at $A$ with radius $d$ and the line with slope $m$ through point $A$ found by considering the angle of segment $AB$ and rotating by an angle $\theta.$